# How can I add a title tag and change size option to a form field in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following ruby code in my view is like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :email, :class => '' %>
```

It renders like this:

```
<input class="" id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="text" />
```

I want to be able to change the size and add a title tag which would look like this:

```
<input class="" id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="40" title="Your Email" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For size, do `:size => 40`

You could try the same for `:title`, but I've never seen it used.

```
<%= f.text_field :email, :class => '', :size => 40, :title => 'whatever' %>
```

Like I said, not sure if the title hash works.